# Need help in C programming linked list

Tags: c, function, singly-linked-list

I'm creating a program using linked list which will later store in a text file. Basically this program will create an inventory, later update it as well. So I've successfully created the inventory (a function) and I've problem with updating it.

The inventory function is asking user to key in inputs, save into a text file and display it. The updating function has to select a particular item first and after that choosing whether to add or subtract the amount and the text file has to be updated at the same time.

So my **problem** is, I'm **not able** to compare the string input from the inventory function with this update function string input. Also, I need to receive an amount of item from user and then add the amount to the existing amount which I had entered in the inventory function earlier.

**Visual Studio** shows me that `String 'code' might not be zero-terminated` and `String 'update' might not be zero-terminated` for the update function.

I'm a beginner so I really need help from all of you, thank you!

This is the linked list codes:

```
struct donations
{
    char supplyName[100], supplyCode[20], donator[150];
    int no_ofShipment;
    float quantityReceived;
    struct donations* ptr;
} *start, *curr, *temp;
```

This is the inventory function (not a `main` function and will be changed later its a function for another main menu as the update function)

```
void main()
{
    void details();
    int i;
    FILE *fp;
    start = curr = NULL;

    curr = start;
    if (start == NULL)
    {
        start = curr = (struct donations *)malloc(sizeof(struct donations));

        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            curr = (struct donations *)malloc(sizeof(struct donations));

            details();

            if (i == 0)
                start = temp = curr;
            else
            {
                temp->ptr = curr;
                temp = curr;
            }
        }
        
        temp->ptr = NULL;
        temp = start;
        printf("\n\t Inventory Created Successfully!");     
        printf("\n\t Recorded to the end of the list!");
    }

    //create file & print output into the file

    if (fopen_s(&fp, "Donation.txt", "w") != 0)
    {
        printf("\nError");
        return;
    }
    if (!fp)
    {
        printf("\n Error in opening file!");
        //_getch();
        return;
    }

    curr = start;
    while (curr)
    {
        fprintf(fp, "%-30s", curr->supplyName);
        fprintf(fp, "%-30s", curr->supplyCode);
        fprintf(fp, "%-30s", curr->donator);
        fprintf(fp, "%10d", curr->no_ofShipment);
        fprintf(fp, "\t%.1f\n", curr->quantityReceived);
        curr = curr->ptr;
    }
    printf("\n\n\t File (records) has been created!");

    fclose(fp);
    
    // display output

    printf("\n\n\n\tDisplay Inventory");
    while (temp)
    {
        printf("\n\n\n\t Name of Supply: %-30s", temp->supplyName);
        printf("Supply Code: %-30s", temp->supplyCode);
        printf("Donator: %-30s", temp->donator);
        printf("No. of Shipment: %10d", temp->no_ofShipment);
        printf("\tQuantity Received: %.1f", temp->quantityReceived);
        temp = temp->ptr;
    }
}

void details()
{
    int i = 0;

    system("cls");
    printf("\tInventory Creation\t");

    printf("\n\n\tEnter Name of Supply: ",(i+1));
    gets_s(curr->supplyName);
    while (getchar() != '\n');

    printf("\n\tEnter Supply Code: ", (i + 1));
    gets_s(curr->supplyCode);
    while (getchar() != '\n');

    printf("\n\tEnter Donator: ", (i + 1));
    gets_s(curr->donator);
    while (getchar() != '\n');

    printf("\n\tEnter No. of Shipment: ", (i + 1));
    scanf_s("%d", &curr->no_ofShipment);
    while (getchar() != '\n');

    printf("\n\tEnter Quantity Received: ", (i + 1));
    scanf_s("%f", &curr->quantityReceived);
    while (getchar() != '\n');
}
```

this is my update function, but not finished yet.

```
void update_DonationQuantity()
{
    char code[10];
    char update[5];
    float quantity, Quantity;
    FILE *fp;

    printf("\n\tUpdate Donation Quantity\t\n");
    printf("\n\n\tSelect donation (CT/HS/FM/SM/OM): ");
    gets_s(code);

    if (strcmp(code, curr->supplyCode) == 0)
    {
        printf("\n\tReceived/Distibuted item (+/-): ");
        gets_s(update);
        while (strcmp(update, "+") && (update, "-") != 0)
        {
            printf("\n\tWrong input, Try Again");
            printf("\n\tReceived/Distibuted item (+/-): ");
            gets_s(update);
        }

        if (strcmp(update, "+") == 0)
        {
            printf("\n\t Enter received amount: ");
            scanf_s("%f", &quantity);
            
            if (fopen_s(&fp, "Donation.txt", "a") != 0)
            {
                printf("\nError");
                return;
            }
            if (!fp)
            {
                printf("\n Error in opening file!");
                //_getch();
                return;
            }

            curr->quantityReceived = quantity + curr->quantityReceived;
            fprintf(fp, "\t%.1f\n", curr->quantityReceived);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, 1-argument [`gets_s()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/gets-s-getws-s?view=msvc-170) shouldn't be available in C...?

Comment: Hi, its used for receive string aka character array it has to include the _s so it can be executed or else visual studio code 2019 wont execute the program

Comment: What makes it any safer than the obsolete `gets()`? Neither of them know the buffer size, unlike MS's `char *gets_s(char *buffer, size_t sizeInCharacters);` which takes the size argument.

Comment: @Beginner: if your compiler does not complain about the missing size argument in `gets_s(curr->supplyName);` you should file a bug report with Microsoft. The second argument is **mandatory**! The need for a size argument is the very reason the compiler prevents you from using `gets()` in the first place. For portable code, you should use `fgets()` instead anyway.

Comment: ...and don't mix the input methods, unless you are very sure of what you are doing. Obtain all the other inputs with `fgets()` too and then convert the string.

Comment: @xing  what should I do instead?

Comment: I'm afraid you compile the program as C++. This would explain why `gets_s()` accepts a single argument and why you cast `malloc()` return values. Microsoft so called *secure* functions are so confusing. Their documentation adds to the confusion: *If the first character read is the end-of-file character, a null character is stored at the beginning of buffer and NULL is returned.* There is no such thing as  *the end-of-file character*! In case the line does not fit in the array, the behavior is obscure and the warning message does not help: `String 'code' might not be zero-terminated`

Comment: What this message implies is: *in case of an error, the contents of the array might not be null terminated*, but this is not what the C Standard says: in case of an error, a null byte is stored into the first element of the array and `NULL` is returned. You should avoid using these non portable functions and use a conforming C compiler.

Comment: @chqrlie MS still recognises the control character `0x1A` (Ctrl-Z) in text files and converts it to `EOF` :)

Comment: @WeatherVane: long live CPM! RIP [Gary Kildall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gary_Kildall)... Still a fan.

Comment: @chqrlie what does Linux do with a Ctrl-D in a text file redirected to stdin, or opened specifically as a file ( MS traps it here as well as from stdin)?

Comment: @WeatherVane: no way! a byte in a file with value `'\004'` is just like any other byte value: `getc()` returns `4` that's it.  MS does still treat 0x1A as an end of file indicator when [reading](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/read?view=msvc-170) files in text mode... This is a dreadful decision rooted in the original design of the CP/M OS where file sizes had a granularity of 1 disk sector: 0x1A was used in the last sector to indicate the end of the text.  The CR/LF convention they can't grow out of was also copied from CP/M albeit it probably predates this OS

Comment: Never use _s functions, they are non-portable and do not add any more security.

Comment: @chqrlie I though it was kept for backward compatibilty with old text files.

Comment: @WeatherVane: also note that in cooked mode, you can still input a 0x04 byte from the terminal by quoting it with ^V (the default LNEXT termios attribute, which can be redefined with `tcsetattr(2)` or `stty(1))`.

Comment: ...certainly MS Notepad no longer writes the `0x1a` character.

Comment: @WeatherVane: yes it is kept for backward compatibility with ancient text files. Current library functions do not write the Ctrl-Z to text files unless they are instructed to do so explicitly (in which case I am not sure what happens).

Comment: @chqrlie it writes an explicitly requested `0x1A` and anything subsequently sent. On reading in text mode it stops at `0x1A` and in binary mode it continues to the actual EOF - as you would expect!

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- `struct donations *ptr;` is confusing: linked lists usually have a `next` member to chain the subsequent list element.
- `void main()` is incorrect: the return type of `main` is `int`.
- `void details();` defining a function in a local scope, while allowed is very bad style. You should move this declaration before the start of the `main` function.
- `if (start == NULL)` is always true.
- `start = curr = (struct donations *)malloc(sizeof(struct donations));` This line is useless and causes a memory leak: both `curr` and `start` are overwritten in the `for` loop just below.
- `if (!fp)` is redundant: if `fopen_s` failed, it would have returned `0`, otherwise `fp` must have been set to a valid pointer. Using `fopen` instead seems simpler and more portable.
- `printf("\n\n\tEnter Name of Supply: ",(i+1));` the `(i+1)` argument is useless. The same problem appears in the next `printf` statements.
- `gets_s(curr->supplyName);` should have a size argument. You might be compiling as C++ for the compiler to accept this. Microsoft has a non-standard template with the same name as the C so call *safe* function `gets_s` they forcefully introduced into the C Standard. This is utmostly confusing. You should use `fgets()`, `scanf()` or a custom made function to read a string into the destination array, consuming the excess characters and the newline if present. `gets_s` does not do that, it behavior if the line entered is too long is obscure... The return value should be checked for errors.
- `while (getchar() != '\n');` is risky: if the stream reaches the end of file before reading a newline, this loop will get stuck in an infinite loop. Furthermore `gets_s()` should have read the newline, so this loop is only useful for the `%d` and `%f` conversions. For this case you could use a `flush_stdin()` function written this way:

  ```
    int flush_stdin(void) {
        int c;
        while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
            continue;
        return c;
    }
  ```